# Join 3 table to find total cost

Tags: oracle, join

We need to find out total cost for each project in XYZ company (from the project). Total cost is considered to be sum of (unit price * quantity) from invoice details table.

1. To find out total cost for each project you need join 3 tables in the query: XYZ_PROJECTS with XYZ_INVOICES (using PROJECT_NUMBER) and XYZ_INVOICES with XYZ_INVOICE_DETAILS (using INVOICE_NUMBER).
2. Go to SQL WorkshopSQL Commands. Write and execute a “select” query to select project number, project name from XYZ_PROJECTS, sum(c.qty * c.Unit_price) from XYZ_INVOICE_DETAILS. (You need to add “group by project_number, project_name” at the end of the query since SUM aggregate function is used). Run the query. Your screen should like as follows

---

I used this to join table but I do not know how to join 3 table at the same time.

```
 select *
 from XYZ_PROJECTS c 
 join XYZ_INVOICES do on c.PROJECT_NUMBER = do.PROJECT_NUMBER

 select * 
 from XYZ_INVOICES i 
 join XYZ_INVOICE_DETAILS do on i.INVOICE_NUMBER = do.INVOICE_NUMBER
```

Maybe I do it wrong.  Please kindly help me.

Answer (score 1):

```
select c.project_number, c.project_name, sum(do.qty * do.Unit_price)
from XYZ_PROJECTS c 
join XYZ_INVOICES i
    on c.PROJECT_NUMBER = i.PROJECT_NUMBER
join XYZ_INVOICE_DETAILS do 
    on i.INVOICE_NUMBER = do.INVOICE_NUMBER
group by c.project_number, c.project_name
```

If you need to include zero cost projects who do not have any invoices yet, use `left outer join` to keep all rows from XYZ_PROJECTS:

```
select c.project_number, c.project_name, sum(do.qty * do.Unit_price)
from XYZ_PROJECTS c 
left join XYZ_INVOICES i 
    on c.PROJECT_NUMBER = i.PROJECT_NUMBER
left join XYZ_INVOICE_DETAILS do 
    on i.INVOICE_NUMBER = do.INVOICE_NUMBER
group by c.project_number, c.project_name
```

Comment: Hi Shannon,  Thank you so much.  I do not need to include zero cost project so I use the first one but I ran into  ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.  What am i missing?

Comment: @StephenLenh, I screwed up the joins. I believe they are correct now.

Comment: @StephenLenh, if you don't get a better answer in the next couple of days, please accept my answer.